# Dynamically display image in a Sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: asp.net, list, c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I want to display image dynamically in a list. I have two columns in a list. The first column contains some numerical values and other contains smiley icon.  My requirement is, if number in first column is greater than 50, I want happy smiley to be appear in a second column in a list, and sad smiley for less than 50 number. Currently I use hyperlink column to display image in a list. And I am adding image manualy.

I am looking forward, if it is possible to automatically display image based on first column number. Something like calculated columns. Lets say,

HyperLink/Picture Formula:

```
 column   =IF([someNumer]>50, "href = c:\Test\happySmiley.ico", "href= c:\Test\happySad.ico" )
```

I was wondering if we could do something like this, or any other suggestion is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [KPI indicators.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/demo-add-kpis-to-your-sharepoint-site-HA010254916.aspx)

You can also find great overview here:
[How to create a SharePoint KPI column](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/05/how-to-create-a-sharepoint-kpi-column/)

And also check similar question on SPSE:
[Make all KPI Status Icons in diamond shape](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19884/make-all-kpi-status-icons-in-diamond-shape)